# NSIS - show Section in SectionGroup only if system id 64bit

Tags: nsis

i have a SectionGroup with two Sections

```
SectionGroup /e "myGroup" GRPCONNECTOR

  Section "sec32" SEC32
   ..
  SectionEnd

  Section "sec64" SEC64
   ..
  SectionEnd 

SectionGroupEnd
```

both are shown in the component-page

now I want the SEC64-section to be shown only, if the running OS is 64 bit. 
how would I do that??

I tried with the common `${if}${RunningX64}` but that fails here.

Comment: It is always helpful if you post your entire script and/or your compiler errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use the macros in x64.nsh to deal with 64-bit/WoW stuff and the helper macros in Sections.nsh to deal with sections:

```
SectionGroup /e "myGroup" GRPCONNECTOR
Section "sec32" SEC32
SectionEnd

Section "sec64" SEC64 ; This must be placed before the usage of ${SEC64} in your .NSI file.
SectionEnd 
SectionGroupEnd

!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh

Function .onInit
${IfNot} ${RunningX64}
    SectionSetText ${SEC64} "" ; Hide the section
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SEC64} ; And uncheck it
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Page Components
Page InstFiles
```